# Trying to autofill a data form with selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to build an automation script with python and selenium. Here is the code so far. I have sensitive info blanked out for privacy reasons. I basically want the handlingunit box to be autofilled with HandlingUnit variable.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

OriginZip = 99501
DestinationZip = 94016
HandlingUnit = 1

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\*******\Desktop\WebAutomation\chromedriver")
driver.maximize_window()


driver.get("***********")
driver.implicitly_wait(1)

#Login Page
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='dropdownMenuButton']").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='UserName']").send_keys('*******')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='Password']").send_keys('*******')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-block']").click()

#2nd Page
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='OriginZip']").send_keys(OriginZip)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='DestinationZip']").send_keys(DestinationZip)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-secondary form-control']").click()

#3rd Page
driver.refresh()  #<-- Add this to fix
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='handlingunits']").send_keys(HandlingUnit) #here is where the error occurs
```

Here is a picture of the 3rd page
[image: 3rdpagepicture]

The error that appears:

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.87)
```

I've tried adding an implicity_wait method, as well as finding elements by ID. Anyone know the proper solution to this?

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML and error stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this-

> 1 .Refresh you page before entering data.
>
> 2.Try to use CSS instead of xpath
>
> 3.use try and catch

for e.g.

```
try:
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#handlingunits']").send_keys(HandlingUnit) 

except (StaleElementReferenceException):

     wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 5,ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(..your code))
     driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#handlingunits").send_keys(HandlingUnit)
```

hope this helps

Comment: Python is indent sensitive. Please fix your code indents.

Comment: Adding: 
driver.refresh()

fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an AJAX refresh is happening at the following line of code

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-secondary form-control']").click()
```

Even though not a best practice, I would suggest to put a explicit wait after this line of code, that too for a significant amount of time (e.g. 30 secs).
If that helps, you can try:

1. Optimizing the explicit wait time by reducing it in steps
2. Try other script synchronizing techniques e.g. WebDriverWait